# google::dense_hash_map vs boost::unordered_map performance issue

Tags: c++, performance, boost, hashmap

I've been recently trying to improve performance of software which spends 60% of time on searching in hashmap (confirmed with valgrind profiler).

Current implementation is using `boost::unordered_map<long long, FrequencyKey>`. I wanted to compare it with `google::dense_hash_map<long long, FrequencyKey>`. I changed one line in my code

```
boost::unordered_map<long long, FrequencyKey> result;
```

to

```
google::dense_hash_map<long long, FrequencyKey> result;
result.set_empty_key(-1);
```

Interface of map is called in 2 places. Before the big loop `result.clear()`. Inside the loop `result[key]`.

With `boost::unordered_map<long long, FrequencyKey>` my software  performance is **118 req/s**. With the changes listed above I am getting **0.5 req/s**.

I am obviously doing something wrong but I cannot figure it out myself after going through the docs and github [code](https://github.com/sparsehash/sparsehash).

I am compiling the code on CentOS 6.5 with gcc/g++ 4.4.7.

Comment: When checking the performance of hash-maps, the first step is to check the collisions that occur. With `std::unordered_map` and similar interfaces, you can iterate over the list of buckets and count the number of items, each time a bucket contains N > 1 items, you have (N-1) collisions which are slowing you down. Other than that... your question unfortunately lacks code: produce a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or suffer useless (to you) answers :x

Answer (score -4):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong. `dense_hash_map` is optimized for memory not speed.

I suspect that either your hash function is really slow or the data is not really good for hash map.

If you have few values in the hash_map (like < 128) try using a vector and doing linear search. It tends to be sufficiently fast sometimes.

If you have a custom hash function try to write a benchmark for it. Valgring might have skipped it if it was inlined in the binary.

Also if you can assign your entries consecutive IDs you can skip the map and just use a vector to store the data. Not always possible, but it's always faster than hash_map.

Last, result[key] is supposed to insert the key with a default value. The constructor of the value might be the source of the problem, or the copy (if you do any). Again this might be inlined as an optimization in the binary so you're not guaranteed to see it in Valgrind. If you didn't expect the insert to happen that might also inflate the map sufficiently to create performance problems.

Comment: Thanks for your input @Sorin, but I am afraid that none of your comments is applicable in my situation. I am storing 500k entries on average and no more than 1.5M. The key is long long with hash fn `std::tr1::hash<long long>`. According to documentation the `dense_hash_map` is optimized for speed and `sparse_hash_map` for memory. Constructor is not heavy for the mapped value and I've tried object pooling with no better performance. Lastly the behavior of inserting default value (when key is not present in map) by operator[] is used on purpose and `boost::unordered_map` works exactly the same.

Comment: @MaciejDonajski sorry none of the suggestions work. Please check the documentation again, one of us got it wrong. If the hash_map is sparse it uses more memory (it's sparse because the used entries are far in between). I might be wrong but probably worth a double check.

Comment: I had the same intuition but the exact quote from the github repo readme is `sparse_hash_map has memory overhead of about 2 bits per hash-map entry, dense_hash_map has a factor of 2-3 memory overhead: if your hashtable data takes X bytes, dense_hash_map will use 3X-4X memory total.` and `sparse_hash_map uses very little space overhead, 1-2 bits per entry.  dense_hash_map is very fast, particulary on lookup.`. But I will try it anyway :).

Comment: It is the opposite, google::dense_hash_map is optimized for speed.